# Spring Data MongoDB: query for month

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I'm working on a webApp with Spring-boot, I am looking to create a query findByMonth(int or String month) but I would like to be able to use for example findByNameAndMonth(String name, month) or findByIdAndMonth() is it possible?
The date has LocalDate type.

I have an Object like this :

```
public final class Alarm {
  @id
  private final String id;
  private final String type;
  // ....
  private final LocalDate date;
```

and its a mongoRepository:

```
 public interface AlarmRepository extends MongoRepository<Alarm, String>{
 }
```

The query is supposed to give the same result as this query for example:

```
db.alarm.find({ $where : 'return this.date.getMonth() == 5'})
```

Comment: yes, http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: which paragraph please !

Comment: read the whole thing... it starts slow, but gets better towards the end... it's not that long and you will find it useful...

or start from JPA Repositories

Comment: Yes, I read it but I can't find what to do :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LocalDate` is stored in MongoDB as ISODate, so it is not possible to access it's properties directly (`date.month` is just not working and method `getMonth()` has to be used).

This causes that use of dates from Spring Data is bit tricky. To solve your issue I would suggest to create this method in your repository:

```
List<Alarm> findByDateBetween(LocalDate from, LocalDate to);
```

But you have to take care of boundary conditions (beginning of a month and end of month).

Another option is to store date as plain object and access month by it's properties, as it is described in [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Spring Data expects the same variable name in repository method name. For ex:
`public final class Alarm {
 @id
 private final String id;
 private final String type;
 ....
 private final LocalDate date;`

Then in your repository, the method name should be as below.

`findByIdAndDate(String id, LocalDate date);
findByIdAndType(String id, String type);`

Comment: Yes I know this my question was to do the same but for just the month not the whole date, like this query **db.alarm.find({ $where : 'return this.date.getMonth() == 5'})**